# Intentional strong reference in a block, is this a good idea?

Tags: ios, objective-c, block

so i have 2 views with an Object in each that is both the same type. I used a block to setup the object in the first view, and i pass this block to the second view when i segue to it, so that the exact same setup can be run for the object in the 2nd view. (for some context its a map, and i add markers and paths to the first map, then i segue to an enlarged version of the map on the second screen that will have the same markers and paths)

now there is one variable that i want to only exist in the first view, but still have an effect in the second view, its going to be a special marker that can have its position changed from the first view (gps update in background only happens in the first view), and the changes will appear in the second view.

so what im effectively going to do is this:

```
@implementation WhereAmIView 
{ 
RMMarker *iAmHere;
void (^setupMap)(RMMapView*);
} 

- (void) setup {

//__block RMMarker *_iAmHere = iAmHere;

    setupMap = ^(RMMapView *mapViewBlock){
        if(!iAmHere)
            iAmHere = [[RMMarker alloc]initWithUIImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"marker-red.png"] anchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0)];

        //there is a bunch of other stuff i have omitted here, but the important bit is above this comment
        [iAmHere setTextForegroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
        [iAmHere changeLabelUsingText:@"You are Here"];
        [markerManager addMarker:iAmHere AtLatLong:appDelegate.currentLocation.coordinate]; //dont worry about this stuff, just put it here to show that stuff is happening
    }

    setupMap(mapView);
}

- (IBAction)enlargeMap:(id)sender {

    MainViewController *mainViewController = (MainViewController*)[self viewController];
    FullScreenMapViewController *fsmvc = [[FullScreenMapViewController alloc] initWithCenter:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(0, 0) andMap:@"tokai2.db"];
    fsmvc->setupMap = setupMap; //this gets run in its viewDidAppear effectively
    [mainViewController presentModalViewController:fsmvc animated:true];
}
```

so is it safe for me to use `iAmHere` like this, since this block will only exist in this view and the next one, so technically retain cycles wont matter? if i use the `_iAmHere` that is commented out in the code instead of `iAmHere` in the block, will changes to `iAmHere` in the first view, make changes to the `_iAmHere` in the second view? it might not be possible to add the same marker to both map views at all, but in theory would this work?

or maybe there is a better way to do this entirely...

Comment: `fsmvc->setupMap` this looks nasty - any specific reason for breaking encapsulation like this?

Comment: cant set a block as an @property it seems, so had to do it like that

Comment: `@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^myBlock)(void);`

Comment: ah, will change it to that then